# Complement of Lie Product Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

For $d \times d$ matrices $X$ and $Y$, Lie product formula asserts that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (e^{X/n}e^{Y/n})^n = e^{X+Y}.
\end{equation}
What if we consider $n \to 0$?

To make sure the question make sense, we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are Hermitian. Then
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (e^{nX}e^{nY})^{\frac{1}{n}} = \, ?
\end{equation}

I am interested in the behavior of the eigenvalues of $(e^{nX}e^{nY})^{\frac{1}{n}}$, in terms of those of $e^X$ and $e^Y$.

Two things are certain: (1) all eigenvalues of $(e^{nX}e^{nY})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ are positive, and (2) the largest eigenvalue of $(e^{nX}e^{nY})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is increasing as $n \mapsto \infty$ (is it bounded?).

I did not find similar question in the literature. Maybe the sequence is divergent. Thanks for your answer.

---

**Update**: I think I get it. The sequence is not bounded (hence divergent).

By the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula, 
\begin{equation}
\log (e^Xe^Y) = X + Y + \frac{1}{2}[X, Y] + \cdots
\end{equation}
So 
\begin{equation}
(e^{nX}e^{nY})^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\frac{1}{n}(nX + nY + \frac{1}{2}[nx, nY] + \cdots)} = e^{X + Y + \frac{n}{2}[X, Y] + \cdots}
\end{equation}

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.